# Are the limitations of a Bond gadget not effecting this explained in the film?

Tags: james-bond, no-time-to-die

In *No Time To Die*, James Bond is given a watch with an EMP gadget, which Q says will burn out anything with a circuit (I forget the exact wording).

Later in the film,

> Bond is infected with the *nanotech* Heracles virus

but unless I missed it

> is there an explanation as to why Heracles isn't affected by the EMP?

Comment: Trying hard not be spoilerific here (and I nearly put another tag on that would have been a slight spoiler), I'm conscious the film is only just out. I *think* the subject of the question puts it in scope for us, but it might also fall into Films/TV.

Comment: From a real-world science perspective, electromagnetic waves don't do great at penetrating living tissue, so there's a good chance that much of the nanotech would be shielded enough to survive and regrow. :-P But we don't do real-world solutions around here.

Comment: As @Randal'Thor said, the most upvoted answer in [this meta thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e) does say that questions specifically about science-fictional technology in spi-fi are ok, and the question is specifically about why a "nanotech virus" isn't disabled by an EMP, that's definitely not an existing real-world technology. Voting to re-open.

Comment: As this question focuses on the sci-fi topic of nanotech viruses, rather than just regular spy-fi technology, I've re-opened (I was vote 4 or 5, a fellow mod agreed they would have been vote 5 of 5) it and edited to clear up some of the points in the question.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Given that small EMPs aren't even sci-fi (you can buy them online for a few pounds), a real-world answer would seem appropriate

Comment: @Valorum where can I buy the nanotech viruses from the film though?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Alibaba

Comment: @FuzzyBoots high-energy electromagnetic waves like X-rays or gamma rays, as produced by an EMP, travel through living tissue just fine. There's even a common medical imaging technique that relies on this fact.

Comment: @GrahamLee: Hmm... back when I posted that, I found a paper analyzing the effect of EMPs on pacemakers, and they basically found that the danger was minimal due to the body largely absorbing the necessary frequency of EMR.

Comment: Ah, and I see I actually quoted that paper in my answer. :-D

Comment: The question should be "Why is Bond's communications headset unaffected?" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few possible answers to this, which depend on how the EMP was implemented and how the nanotech was implemented.

### Human Bodies are resistant to EMP

Due to a combination of conductive skin and more insulated insides, [the charge of an EMP pulse is likely to travel along the surface of the body rather than penetrate](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-come-emp-doesnt-affect-humans-or-does-it.652306/post-4161466). This theoretical point may be supported by [a 1991 US Army report on the effects of EMP on pacemakers](https://preparednessadvice.com/the-effects-of-electromagnetic-pulse-emp-on-cardiac-pacemakers/) which concluded that internal devices were unlikely to be damaged.

### Nanotech may be too small to be affected

[EMP pulses work by inducing voltage in an antenna, intended or not](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/153444/883) and said antenna needs to be of a reasonable fraction of the wavelength of the electromagnetic radiation to cause damage. Nanotech, being a small as it is, may not actually be large enough to pick up the pulse and generate voltage enough to cause damage.

### He just may not have had time to use it

Bond uses the EMP on his watch against a particular villain in the film, and then is infected a bit later. Most EMPs work either via an explosive charge or capacitors. The former tend to be one-use devices and the latter require an extensive period of time to recharge. Even if the EMP might have been effective against the nanotech, the odds are good that Bond just never got a chance to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's an easy answer, actually. The Heracles nanobots in question are biological, not electro-mechanical, so they would not be affected by an EMP - unlike an electronic object like Primo's cybernetic eye.

Comment: Do you have a source that supports the statement 'the nanobots are biological'? IIRC there's no statement to that effect in the film, and the term nanobot isn't widely accepted that way. But in the film we do see Obruchev programming the viruses with the DNA profiles of the SPECTRE operatives - how does that work if they're biological.

Comment: Wouldn't nanoBOT imply a mechanical basis?  "nano virus" would suggest a biological basis, or perhaps "novel virus"....